# How can I erase my string way quicker

Tags: c++

I am supposed to write a program that takes in string like "pre#ogrann##mmink#g" and returns "programming", it is like your backspace button is broken and when you hit it you get '#' instead of erasing the char out, and I have to fix it. I have working code here under but it is way to slow, and I might have to deal with huge string, any suggestion how I could do it better/faster?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {


    string str;
    while(cin >> str) {
        bool done = false;
        while(!done) {
            if((int)str.find('#')>-1) {
                str.erase(str.find('#')-1, 2);
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        }
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The line:   done = true; should be moved to after str.erase  or just call str_replace instead of the code to replace all instances of '#' wth ''

Comment: But there might be more than one # and I have to do this for every #

Comment: What do you mean by "way to[o] slow" exactly?

Comment: First, you are doing find twice when you only need to do it once.  Also, you are searching from the beginning of the string each time when you only need to move forward from the last one found.

Comment: Process the string as char array element by element. Then add each element to a vector (push_back), unless you encounter a #, then you pop_back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could adapt the implementation of `std::remove`: use an iterator to keep track of a place to "copy to" which could then be decremented when you encounter a `#` along with an iterator to keep track of where to "copy from".  Though depending on the desired semantics if there are too many `#` you may need to be careful not to run off the start of the string.  Then, at the end, do a `str.erase(pos, str.end());` to cut off the remainder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. I haven't tested it to see if it is actually faster, but as it has a complexity of *O(N)*, I think it should be fast enough:

```
while (std::cin >> input) {
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(input.length());

    for (auto ch : input) {
        if (ch == '#') {
            if (result.length() > 0)
                result.pop_back();
            continue;
        }

        result += ch;
    }

    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Leading `#`s should probably be ignored (as it is usually done in UIs) or trigger an exception. This version invokes UB in that case.

Comment: @5gon12eder Good catch, thanks :)

Comment: So, something like I suggested in the comments it is ;)

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Jup, didn't notice that :) Next time, post an answer, as they are not supposed to be comments ;D

Comment: @Rakete1111 true. However, I was posting from my smart phone, and don't have an IDE on it. So I couldn't check my code.

Comment: By the way: of course your code is faster then the original. Just imagine what `string.erase`does in terms of complexity. you could add to your code `result.reserve(input.size());`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string s = "pre#ogrann##mmink#g";


int main() {
  string out;
  int len = s.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(s[i] == '#') {
      s.erase(i-1,2);
      len = s.length();
      i -= 2;
    }
  }
  cout << s;
  return 0;
}
```

This produces a working output.